# Demasiados problemas con PHPMailer

Tags: php

El día de ayer formule una pregunta en la cual enviaba un correo con la función de PHPMailer pero lo mandaba en blanco. El día de hoy trato de enviarlo y llega a mi bandeja de entrada pero el problema es que llega como si yo mismo me lo enviara, no esta tomando en cuenta los datos del FROM. Ayuda por favor el código es el siguiente:

```
    <?php 

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');
//require_once('PHPMailerAutoload.php');

require('vistas/mail.view.php');


    define("destino", "gspindolab@gmail.com");
    define("farmacia", "Guillermo");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST') {
        $nombre=filter_var($_POST['nombre'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $de=filter_var($_POST['de'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $telefono=filter_var($_POST['telefono'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $asunto=filter_var($_POST['asunto'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $mensaje='
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Cuerpo del mensaje</h1>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';
        $mensaje.=filter_var($_POST['mensaje'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


        $correo = new PHPMailer(); //Creamos una instancia en lugar usar mail()

        $correo->IsSMTP();
        $correo->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true));

        // optional
        // used only when SMTP requires authentication  
        $correo->SMTPAuth = true;
        $correo->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $correo->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $correo->Port = 587;
        $correo->Username = 'correo@gmail.com';
        $correo->Password = 'password';

        //Usamos el SetFrom para decirle al script quien envia el correo
        $correo->SetFrom($de, $nombre);

        //Usamos el AddReplyTo para decirle al script a quien tiene que responder el correo
        $correo->AddReplyTo($de, $nombre);

        //Usamos el AddAddress para agregar un destinatario
        $correo->AddAddress(destino, farmacia);

        //Ponemos el asunto del mensaje
        $correo->Subject = $asunto;

        /*
         * Si deseamos enviar un correo con formato HTML utilizaremos MsgHTML:
         * $correo->MsgHTML("<strong>Mi Mensaje en HTML</strong>");
         * Si deseamos enviarlo en texto plano, haremos lo siguiente:
         * $correo->IsHTML(false);
         * $correo->Body = "Mi mensaje en Texto Plano";
         */
        $correo->MsgHTML($mensaje);



        //Si deseamos agregar un archivo adjunto utilizamos AddAttachment
        //$correo->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");
        $correo->CharSet = "UTF­8";
        //$correo->Encoding = "quoted­printable";

        //Enviamos el correo
        if(!$correo->Send()) {
          echo "Hubo un error: " . $correo->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
          echo "Mensaje enviado con exito.";
        }

        }
 ?>
```

Comment: Quizás me esté perdiendo algo pero...
¿Porque creas dos instancias distintas?
¿Porque re-instancias $mail?
Si solo creas una y la usas debería funcionar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fin lo logre y fue agregando la siguiente línea:

```
$correo->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' => false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true));
```

y agregando también la clase:

```
require_once('class.smtp.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa esta función:

```
function enviar_correo($destinatarios, $mail_asunto, $mail_contendio, $from, $from_name, $archivos_adjuntos_ruta,$archivos_adjuntos_temp){
$mail= new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$body= $mail_contendio;
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the protocol to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "smtp.farmaciassanasana.com.mx"; // SMTP server
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->Subject = $mail_asunto;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$destinatarios=explode(",", $destinatarios);
if(!empty($destinatarios)){
foreach($destinatarios as $un_destinatario){
$mail->AddAddress($un_destinatario); //destinatarios
}
}else{
return false;
}
if(!empty($archivos_adjuntos_ruta)){
foreach($archivos_adjuntos_ruta as $archivo){
$mail->AddAttachment($archivo); // attachment
}
}
if(!empty($archivos_adjuntos_temp)){
foreach($archivos_adjuntos_temp as $nombrearchivo=>$contenidoArchivo){
$mail->AddStringAttachment($contenidoArchivo,$nombrearch ivo,'base64');
}
}
$mail->Timeout = 20;
if($mail->Send()) {
return array(true);
}else {
return array(false,"Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);
}
}
```

y aca algunos ejemplos para invocarla:

```
$archivos_adjuntos_ruta=array($path1,path2);
$archivos_adjuntos_temp=array(utf8_decode($strfile PDF)=>$strContenidoPdf,utf8_decode($strNomArch)=>$ strContenidoXml);
enviar_correo($Email_destinatarios_string_separado_por_comas,$email_asunto, $mail_contendio_en_html,$correo_remitente,$nombre_remitente,array(),archivos_adjuntos_temp);//los archivos estan en variables temporales
enviar_correo($Email_destinatarios_string_separado_por_comas,$email_asunto, $mail_contendio_en_html,$correo_remitente,$nombre_remitente,$archivos_adjuntos_ruta,array()) ;//los archivos estan en rutas en disco
enviar_correo($Email_destinatarios_string_separado_por_comas,$email_asunto, $mail_contendio_en_html,$correo_remitente,$nombre_remitente,$archivos_adjuntos_ruta,archivos _adjuntos_temp);//ambas opciones al mismo tiempo
```

Si asi sigues teniendo problemas, lo mas probable es que sea alguna mala configuración en tu servidor SMTP, o tu html mal armado.
Y otra cosa, la función no usa login, pero si lo usas tendrás que agregar estas dos lineas:

```
$mail->Username   = "soporte@farmaciassanasana.com.mx";
$mail->Password   = "mipassword"
```