# Error en el envio de mail en php

Tags: php

He intentado de mil maneras diferentes pero no le encuentro una solución a este problema. Estoy intentando enviar un mail con el código que les adjunto a continuación, el cual tengo en otros dos sitios web y funcionan perfectamente. Si alguien me puede ayudar con este tema le agradecería mucho.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

//Preferencias
$email_to = "mail@direccion.com.ar";
$email_subject = "Contacto desde el sitio web";
// Aquí se deberían validar los datos ingresados por el usuario
if(!isset($_POST['nombre']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['texto'])) {

    header('Location: error-contacto.php');
}

$email_message = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
$email_message .= "Nombre: " . $_POST['nombre'] . "\n\n";
$email_message .= "E-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n";
$email_message .= "Núm. de Pasajeros: " . $_POST['pasajeros'] .                     "\n\n";
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
        $email_message .= "La persona no sabe exactamente las     fechas.\n\n";
    }
    else{
       $email_message .= "Fecha de llegada: " . $_POST['llegada'] .     "\n\n";
       $email_message .= "Fecha de salida: " . $_POST['salida'] .     "\n\n";
    }
$email_message .= "Mensaje:\n " . $_POST['texto'] . "\n\n";

// Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
$headers = 'From: '.$_POST['email']."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$_POST['email']."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$resultado = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message,     $headers);
    if ($resultado ==true) 
        { 
            header('Location: gracias.php');
        } 
        else{ 
            header('Location: error-contacto.php');
        }  
}
?>
```

Seguí el consejo de @abrahamhs y empece a utilizar PhpMailer, el problema es que ahora cuando lo utilizo me tira http Error 500

```
require_once('includes/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$direccion = $_POST['email'];

$body = "Detalles del formulario de contacto:\n\n";
$body .= "Nombre: " . $nombre . "\n\n";
$body .= "E-mail: " . $direccion . "\n\n";
$body .= "Núm. de Pasajeros: " . $_POST['pasajeros'] . "\n\n";
    if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
        $body .= "La persona no sabe exactamente las fechas.\n\n";
    }
    else{
       $body .= "Fecha de llegada: " . $_POST['llegada'] . "\n\n";
       $body .= "Fecha de salida: " . $_POST['salida'] . "\n\n";
    }
$body .= "Mensaje:\n " . $_POST['texto'] . "\n\n";
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                 
$mail->Host = 'mail.midireccion.com'
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'email@midireccion.com';
$mail->Password = 'contrasena'; 

$mail->SetFrom('email@midireccion.com', 'Contacto desde el sitio web');
$mail->AddReplyTo($direccion);
$mail->Subject = 'Contacto desde el sitio web';
$mail->AltBody = $body;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress('email@midireccion.com', 'Contacto desde el sitio web');
if(!$mail->send()) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
header('Location: gracias.php');
}
```

Estuve probando y todo código que coloco antes que el $mail->send() se ejecuta. ¿Puede ser un error de configuración del servidor? Cuando ejecuto la función phpinfo me sale que el puerto SMTP es 25, pero en los datos de mi cuenta dice que es 587 ¿Cuál uso?

---

Ya tengo PhpMailer configurado pero al ejecutarlo y tratar de enviar un mail me aparece el siguiente error:

> 2017-03-11 15:27:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-c037-dr.dattaweb.com ESMTP
>   Exim 4.87_1 #2 Sat, 11 Mar 2017 12:27:00 -0300 220- We do not
>   authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or
>   bulk e-mail. 2017-03-11 15:27:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO
>   midominio.com.ar 2017-03-11 15:27:00 SERVER -> CLIENT:
>   250-c037-dr.dattaweb.com Hello midominio.com.ar [200.58.110.24]
>   250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH LOGIN
>   250-STARTTLS 250 HELP 2017-03-11 15:27:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
>   2017-03-11 15:27:00 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead 2017-03-11
>   15:27:00 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 2017-03-11
>   15:27:00 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2017-03-11 15:27:00 SERVER -> CLIENT:
>   221 c037-dr.dattaweb.com closing connection 2017-03-11 15:27:00 SMTP
>   connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer
>   Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

No se si debo tener que configurar algo en el servidor o si debo agregar o quitar lineas de código php, pero estoy usando el puerto 587 y tengo las configuraciones `SMTPAuth = true`
`SMTPSecure = 'tls'`

¿Qué otra configuración debo realizar para que los emails se envíen correctamente y el servidor me lo autorice?

Comment: y el codigo????

Comment: Buena pregunta. En la vista previa aparece, no sé por que aca no

Comment: no aparecía porque necesitaba un espacio extra entre tu código y el texto que hiciste

Comment: Ah buenisimo, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: _el cual tengo en otros dos sitios web y funcionan perfectamente_ En efecto, el código parece correcto. Tampoco comentas en tu pregunta si te da algún mensaje de error. ¿Has visto el errorlog de la carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo PHP desde el cual envías los emails?  ¿Te muestra el `header('Location: error-contacto.php');`? o... ¿qué ocurre? Sería bueno que digas en la pregunta lo que sucede cuando haces el intento.

Comment: Entra en el ultimo      header('Location: error-contacto.php'); o sea que la función mail devuelve el valor False

Comment: yo veo todo mal (pero obvio nunca he usado la funcion mail), empezando porque no hay servidor de correos, ni tampoco ningun protocolo de correos como SMTP ¿Porque mejor no usas PHPmailer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268012/phpmailer-v-mail-for-a-simple-contact-form
Aqui esta mi ejemplo:
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19735/demasiados-problemas-con-phpmailer/19739#19739

Comment: creo que el código no era necesario si dices que en un servidor funcionaba y en otro no. Me parece que tiene que ver con la configuración del servidor de correo.  ya hay una respuesta muy amplia sobre las posibles soluciones en [ESen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/4987172)

Comment: @JoaquínBozzalla, es curioso que no te este dando error, ya que estas intentando hacerlo usando `SMTP`, pero en tu código no veo que hayas incluido el archivo [`class.smtp.php`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#minimal-installation). Intenta hacerlo como lo hacen en [este ejemplo](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps)

Comment: > PUEDES QUE TENGAS UN SERVIDOR QUE NO PROVEA EL SERVICIO DE EMAILS, TU
> CÓDIGO PUEDE ESTAR PERFECTO PERO SI NO TIENES UN SERVIDOR CON ESE
> SERVICIO NUNCA TE FUNCIONARÁ.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se parece a algo que ya me pasó, pido disculpas si no doy la respuesta pero aun no puedo hacer comentarios.

**E problema:**
Esto es problema con el proveedor ya que ellos tienen su propia seguridad hacen bloqueo de ciertas características que usa el phpMailer.

**Mi solucion:**
Usa la funcion nativa de PHP `mail()`, ya se que es ortodoxo y no permite autenticacion y demas, pero fue lo que me funciono y no he tenido problemas hasta el momento.

**UPDATE 1: SOLUCION**

usa la funcion `mail()` de php

Comment: Considera editar la respuesta para dar un ejemplo un poquito más completo